# Why can't I use OpenCV (C++) on my macOS after install?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14

I installed OpenCV with Homebrew on my macOS. When I open a C++ project, I still cannot include its headers to the file.

Comment: You need to config your header search path of your project. If you installed OpenCV with Homebrew, the "correct" location for headers is /usr/local/Cellar/opencv2/2.x.x/include. There, you would find a subdir opencv2, hence it makes #include "opencv2/core.hpp" work. Another option would be to soft link that opencv2` directory to standard header path /usr/local/include

Comment: Are you talking about an Xcode project ? Make sure you have your homebrew include directory in the header search path (default is /usr/local/include). Alternatively you might want to add the OpenCV includes to your project - this makes them available both to the compiler and also makes it easy for you to look up function prototypes etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how homebrew installs it, but to get the necessary flags, I usually use `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` in my makefiles to get the proper `-I` and `-L` paths. Did homebrew install any `.pc` (`pkg-config`) files?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CMake, then you have to add 2 lines to your CmakeLists.txt file. It should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(learn)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) # first line to add

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(learn main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(learn ${OpenCV_LIBS}) # second line to add
```